# Who is this character being cosplayed in Japan Expo 2014?

Tags: cosplay

This is a snapshot from JAPAN EXPO 2014. I don't know the character, so does anyone know who this character is? [Here](http://youtu.be/UaBGgzEH_aE?t=33s) is the source video.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Aion](http://na.aiononline.com/en/) cosplay, those wings she wearing are [Hyperion Wings](http://aiondatabase.net/us/item/187000121/).

She's (Of') part of a French cosplay group called "[Les Cosplayeuses Emplumées](https://www.facebook.com/VicNyophelieEtNanouCosplay)."